# How do I find the Chromium source code that matches Puppeteer's `chromium_revision`?

Tags: puppeteer

I need to run [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) with a custom Chromium build (so that we don't need x11 on Linux). The `chromium_revision` property in `package.json` does not appear to be tied to any git revision, tag, or specific Chromium version, at least none that I can find.

How I find the Chromium source code that matches Puppeteer's `chromium_revision`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the Chromium source code that matches Puppeteer's [`chromium_revision`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/package.json#L11) in [`package.json`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/package.json) by following this link:

```
https://crrev.com/[chromium_revision]
```

The current Chromium Revision source code (as of 08/09/2018) can be found here:

https://crrev.com/579032

Comment: Yaya! Thank you, Grant. That's *exactly* what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

When installing, puppeteer should install chromium with it. If that isnt the case, have you looked at [this thread](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3027)?

Comment: I work with one of the people on that thread, and it doesn't help, unfortunately. I *think* that the chromium_revision is an SVN id, but I'm not sure.

Comment: maybe https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/m/#!topic/chromium-discuss/xPuP33JExn0 solves it? I dont understand it, but maybe it helps you